# How to make a group in different columns in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, multiple-columns

I'm trying to take one group and put it in two different columns(Separate Male and Female in different columns) Just like in the image shown.

[image]

What I have tried is this:

```
1.  In Details section's 'Section Expert', select 'Format with Multiple Columns'
2.  Select the (now visible) Layout tab
3.  In Layout tab set width = 3 , Horizontal = .01 , tick across then down bullet then click ok.
```

But this gives me not the result that I want. Can someone please give me an idea on how to deal with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After having my research. This solves the issue.

```
1.  In Details section's 'Section Expert', select 'Format with Multiple Columns'
2.  Select the (now visible) Layout tab
3.  In Layout tab set width = 3 , Horizontal = .01 , tick across then down bullet then click ok.
4. In the group footer section "Check the Print at the bottom of Page"
```

That will separate the Male and Female in two columns